# Extract all the rows using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have to extract/scrape data from the website designated below. The dilemma I am having right now is that the website is defaulted to show only 1000 rows and even when I click ***Export to Excel***, it only exports the 1000 rows instead of the 237,593 rows listed on the website. How can I get Python to extract all of the 237,593 records of data from the website. Please let me know if ***Selenium*** is the accurate module to do this task.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx")

number_option = driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnSearch")
number_option.click()

delay = 3 
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"cplMain_btnExportToExcel")))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"


search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnExportToExcel")
search_button.click()


driver.close()
driver.quit()

print 'ALL DONE'
```

Comment: looks like it won't let you export more than 1000 at a time

Comment: Thanks Shane, is there any other way of tackling this.

Comment: Well, you can always brute force but that could take quite a while...

Comment: Selenium is an automation tool, if you can do it manually then selenium can probably automate it. In your case, it looks like a site limitation and hence you probably will not be able to "Crack" it. So, I suggest finding a way to manually do it and apply it thru selenium.

Comment: There has to be another module out there that I could look into. Python is too good to be a tool to show me dead end in this peculiar situation.

Comment: You could use modules like `requests` to do the scraping job, but it's just there's **no more than** 1000 results can be pulled out from the server at a time(unless there's some kind of backdoor, which won't be easy to find), so unless you are patient enough and can come up with a good "search strategy" to max out the combinations and get 1000 records each time, then join all records and remove duplicates, you can eventually get there. But it's a lot of work...